# '#' symbol in Kendo UI

Tags: javascript, html

is there any other way to do screen navigation without having '#' symbol in the codes? For example:below code there is a '#'

a href="#bar" data-role="button"

The '#' is causing termination error in my program.

Thank you.

Comment: it is the [id-selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) from jQuery, you can use a [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) instead

Comment: how are you saying the `#` is terminating the programe

Comment: Could you use URL Variables?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can safely use '#' following their document

> If your template includes a "#" that is not part of a binding expression, you must escape that value or it will cause a template compliation error (this is common in Kendo UI Mobile where # is often used for view navigation). You can escape any literal "#" in JavaScript strings using "\\#" and in HTML script templates using "\#".

http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/framework/templates/overview

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're referring to this:

```
<a href="#">click here</a>
```

If so you can do this, but it throws errors in some browser (old version of ie)

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)">click here</a>
```

Further you could throw a link in there and prevent it with jquery

```
<a href="www.aol.com">click here</a>
```

JQuery

```
$('a').onClick(function(e){
 e.stoppropagation();
 e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: actually I am using tabstrip and each tab is a screen. So when I click on tab 1 it should navigate me to tab 1 screen. So I am using this method: <div data-role="view" id="tabstrip-sales" data-title="Sales History" data-layout="mobile-tabstrip"> <div data-role="tabstrip">
            <a href="#tabstrip-sales" data-icon="history">Sales</a>
        </div>